# Does an analytic continuation for a particular Leibniz series exist?

Tags: analytic-continuation

Define a Leibniz series as follows,
\begin{eqnarray*}
L(x) & = & \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{k}e^{-kx}\ln k,\ \ x>0
\end{eqnarray*}

I have two questions: (I) Is there an analytical form for $L(x)$?
(II) Does the analytic continuation for $L(x)$ from region $x>0$
to region $x<0$ exist?

Comment: Do you have motivations for this problem? What have you tried?